# few fonts are not rendering in any browser on deployed version of app but renders on localhost

Tags: css, font-face, stylus, custom-font

I am in trouble with custom fonts in my react application. I used font-face for using my custom fonts. Every element in on my screen gets rendered with desired fonts but when application goes online (deployed) some elements are not getting the fonts.

On deployed application fonts when I see fonts under network tab I can see the fonts fetched

[image]

This is my styl file. So the table header and detail-name are getting rendered with fonts on deployed version but others are not. In localhost everything gets rendered properly.

```
.table-header
        font-family montserrat

    .detail-type
        font-family museo700


    .file-channel
        font-family museo500
        font-weight 700

    .file-duration
        font-family museo500
        font-weight 700


    .file-upload-date
        font-family museo500
        font-weight 700


    .file-tx-date
        font-family museo500
        font-weight 700

    .file-assignee
        font-family museo500
        font-weight 700

    .item-file-details
        display flex
        align-items center
        margin 8px 0
        width auto
        .file-image
            height 80px
            flex-shrink 0
            width 60px
            background-color rgba(#000, 0.12)
        .details
            margin-left 8px
            .detail-name
                font-family museo700
                font-size 18px
                margin 0
```

This is my font.styl file

```
@font-face
    font-family 'museo_sans700'
    src url('/public/fonts/museosans_0-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('/public/fonts/museosans_0-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight normal
    font-style normal

@font-face
    font-family 'museo_sans300'
    src url('/public/fonts/museosans-300-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('/public/fonts/museosans-300-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight normal
    font-style normal

@font-face
    font-family 'museo_sans500'
    src url('/public/fonts/museosans-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('/public/fonts/museosans-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight normal
    font-style normal

@font-face
    font-family 'montserratregular'
    src url('/public/fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('/public/fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight normal
    font-style normal
```

Comment: Is the address `your-host.com/public/fonts/museosans-webfont.woff` accessible?

Comment: yes. When I go to this url then the fonts gets downloaded. That means it's accessible. Right?

Comment: Yes. I don't see any error though. Maybe posting the parts of your transpiled stylus (i.e. your CSS) with the `@font-face` declaration helps to solve your problem. I assume, you checked your console for any errors? Are the font files in the Sources tab in the DevTools?

Comment: There is no error in console.

Comment: Well, the styles have things like `museo500` while the font-face says `'museo_sans500'`...